# i don't know where is the error , i used linux out of the virtual machine

Tags: java

I try to compile a simple java window code just with one button in terminal using javac and this is the result:

code:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class ventana1 extends Frame{


     private Button b1;

     public ventana1(){

        super("esta es mi ventana");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        b1 = new Button("b1");
        add(b1);
        setSize(300,300);
        setVisible(true);



    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

         ventana1 v1 = new ventana1();

    }


}
```

error message:

```
root@Vostro:/home/ramiro/Documents# sudo java ventana1
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ff48671a009, pid=28886, tid=28887
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: /home/ramiro/Documents/core
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/ramiro/Documents/hs_err_pid28886.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Aborted

I have no idea what this happen , I compile a hello world and it work

Comment: This doesn't look like problem in `java` code, but in implementation of JVM. What is your Java version? Consider changing it. Aside from that, why are you using old technology? After AWT there was Swing and now we have JavaFX.

Comment: root@Vostro:/home/ramiro/Documents# java -version
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
root@Vostro:/home/ramiro/Documents#

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you use an outdated version of Java. I suggest to do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt get upgrade
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-9-*
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

This updates your Linux distribution and installs the default Java runtime environment.

Comment: i think i used that version

Comment: I don't think so. Your Java version dates from 2016 (see 7th line of your error message). Since Java 9.0 dates from September 2017, you are probably running a beta version with this bug in it.

Comment: @rr4m1r0 That is very unlikely. Newest version of Java is 12, but version 11 has LTS (long term support) so it would probably be installed as default one.

Comment: i will reinstall the jre like you say and compile and run again, i change awt to swing and went i run it the window 
showed up very fast and 
disappeared and then showed me an error like the previous one

Comment: root@Vostro:/home/ramiro/Documents# ls
ventana1.class  ventana1.java
root@Vostro:/home/ramiro/Documents# java ventana1
bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
root@Vostro:/home/ramiro/Documents#

Comment: My guess is that under the user root, you have an ancient Java 9 beta version, which is used when you sudo. Now you need to do, is install Java system-wide for all users by `sudo apt-get install defauly-jre`. Then check if Java is available by doing `which java` and `java -version`.

Comment: If you also want to develop Java code, install the development kit (jdk) instead of just the runtime (jre): `sudo apt-get install default-jdk`